# Merge data from multiple tables based on a key in Kusto

Tags: azure-log-analytics, azure-data-explorer, kql

I'm trying to merge multiple tables in Azure Log Analytics. Each table has a unique column and a common column. Merging them with Join() is inefficient because I can only do two tables at a time. Union() seems to be the correct function but when I merge my tables I ended with duplicate rows in my common column.

Example:

```
// CPU usage
let CPU_table=VPN_Metrics_CL | extend timestamp = (todatetime(ts_s)+7h) 
| where metric_s == "system/cpmCPUTotal1Min.rrd"  
| extend region = substring(host_s,0,4)
| summarize maxCPU = max(val_d) by region
| extend score_CPU = case(maxCPU <= 59, 0, 
                          maxCPU <= 79, 1, 
                          3)
| project score_CPU, region;
// Memory usage
let Memory_table=VPN_Metrics_CL| extend timestamp = todatetime(ts_s)+7h
| where metric_s in ("hw_mem_used_pct") and val_d >= 0 and host_s contains "vpn"
| extend region = substring(host_s,0,4)
| summarize maxMemory = max(val_d) by region
| extend score_mem = case(maxMemory <= 59, 0, 
                          maxMemory <= 79, 1, 
                          3)
| project score_mem, region;
union CPU_table, Memory_table
```

I plan on having a total of 10+ tables.

Here is the result:

```
score_mem  |  score_CPU  |  region
    0                         USA
                 0            USA
  etc. etc.
```

How can I merge rows based on a key? The key being the region.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If the source is the same table - the most efficient way will be using conditional aggregates:

```
let isCpuMetric = (metric_s:string) {metric_s == "system/cpmCPUTotal1Min.rrd"};
let isMemoryMetric =  (metric_s:string, val_d:double, host_s:string) {metric_s in ("hw_mem_used_pct") and val_d >= 0 and host_s contains "vpn"};
VPN_Metrics_CL 
| extend timestamp = (todatetime(ts_s)+7h) 
| extend region = substring(host_s,0,4)
| where isCpuMetric(metric_s) or isMemoryMetric(metric_s, val_d, host_s)
| summarize maxCPU = maxif(val_d, isCpuMetric(metric_s)), maxMemory=maxif(val_d, isMemoryMetric(metric_s, val_d, host_s)) by region
| extend score_mem = case(maxMemory <= 59, 0, maxMemory <= 79, 1, 3),
         score_CPU = case(maxCPU <= 59, 0, maxCPU <= 79, 1, 3)
```

If the sources are different - you can still join or lookup operator. If you have results R1 .. RN - coming from a sub-queries:

```
R1 
| lookup R2 on Region
| lookup R3 on Region
...
```

Docs for lookup operator: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/lookupoperator

Comment: I've never used lookup before. I ended up renaming every score to "score", then using a Union to merge all the tables together and produce a total score using Summarize sum(score by region). 

But I like what you did at the beginning of your example, it's much cleaner.

Answer (score 0):

I found it easier to give every category's score column the same name: "score"
Then with Union, I merge all the tables and summarize a total score.

```
union CPU_table, Memory_table, AAA_table, bw_data, more_tables.....
| summarize score_total = sum(score) by region, bin(timestamp, $__interval)
| project score_total, region, timestamp
```

Comment: This answer doesn't match the question requirements: where each metric should have been placed in its own column.